# Random arguments validation

Tags: c++, validation, arguments, startup

I have a program **A** which can be started by my program **B**. So I don't want to allow my users to start the program **A** from Windows Explorer or command line or by any other means. So my idea was to pass an argument to program **A** from program **B**, which gets validated at the startup, but it's too easy to bypass. For example [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) shows the argument of each running program.

So maybe I should generate a random text and pass that as an argument, but I have to reproduce that in the program **A** too, for the validation. So maybe the randomness of the string should depend on the time of the computer, or something like that? What do you guys recommend me, is it a bad way to start with?

Comment: Why not use executable permissions of the file, allowing only you the access rights?

Comment: you should look into public/private keys algorithms

Comment: @Thesane I already looked those algorithms (especially crypto++ library), but I must generate a new key every time in A, and the same in B to validate it. So I stucked again...

Comment: I see, one other option is to use one of the IPC https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx to communicate between the programs. this way will hide the exchange of information. There are other IPC methods for linux as well, depending on your platform

Comment: also you can use server/client mechanism to ensure that program A will only function after successful connection from program B which you can use internal credentials to authenticate. notice that this will require starting program A before B but will only execute relevant parts after B connection. I am not sure if this works for you or no

Comment: @Thesane IPC and also the server is a great solution for me. Write it as an answer and I'm gonna apply it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can IPC (Inter process communication) methods to communicate between the programs. Check [Here for windows methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx). This way you can hide the data exchanged between the programs. 
Also you can use client/server mechanism to allow program A to work only if program B is connected.